# How to change the Partition Label on the vfat filesystem located on device /dev/sda1?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning

**Note:**  this is about changing the Partition Label and ***not*** the
filesystem label

```
lsblk -e7 -o type,name,path,size,pttype,fstype,label,partlabel   # see both, filesystem label and Partition Label   

TYPE NAME        PATH             SIZE PTTYPE FSTYPE LABEL       PARTLABEL
disk sda         /dev/sda         1.9G dos                       
part └─sda1      /dev/sda1        1.9G dos    vfat   IC RECORDER 
disk sdb         /dev/sdb           0B                           
disk sdc         /dev/sdc        29.2G dos                       
part └─sdc1      /dev/sdc1       29.2G dos    vfat   x_8GBFAT_32 
disk nvme0n1     /dev/nvme0n1   465.8G gpt                       
part ├─nvme0n1p1 /dev/nvme0n1p1   512M gpt    vfat               EFI System Partition
part └─nvme0n1p2 /dev/nvme0n1p2 465.3G gpt    ext4
```

just showing sda1 with lsblk header:

```
lsblk -e7 -o type,name,path,size,pttype,fstype,label,partlabel |grep -i 'sda1\|label'

TYPE NAME        PATH             SIZE PTTYPE FSTYPE LABEL       PARTLABEL
part └─sda1      /dev/sda1        1.9G dos    vfat   IC RECORDER
```

after the correct command is given then target output adds DOS_PT_TYPE:

```
lsblk -e7 -o type,name,path,size,pttype,fstype,label,partlabel |grep -i 'sda1\|label'

TYPE NAME        PATH             SIZE PTTYPE FSTYPE LABEL       PARTLABEL
part └─sda1      /dev/sda1        1.9G dos    vfat   IC RECORDER DOS_PT_TYPE
```

using

```
neofetch --stdout | grep 'OS:'
```

**result:**   OS: Kubuntu 22.04.1 LTS x86_64

**How do you change the Partition Label on the vfat filesystem located on device /dev/sda1?**

--

Comment: Never heard of partlabel's  existing except on gpt disks. In that case, you'd use gdisk to change it.

Comment: Guesswork: `gnome-disks` (aka. `Disks`) or the file-system specific `label` shell utility. (e.g. `mlabel`, `dosfslabel`, `fatlabel`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
sudo dosfslabel /dev/sda1 "THIS IS LABEL"
```

Note about the uppercase, if you use a lowercase you will get a warning.

Comment: `Note: this is about changing the Partition Label and not the filesystem label`